# NodeJS : Passport JWT(v4.0.0) failed to authenticate user from POSTMAN Rest Client , Always return Unauthorized

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, passport-jwt

I am using `express js` as backend framework, currently working on login authentication module using [Passport-JWT](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/),

I want to use authentication middleware on private routes .

I don't want to write `passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}` on every route , instead i want to make one function and use it on every request like

```
router.get('/current',isAuthenticated,controllers.auth.user);
```

login authentication working properly , but after that when I access private route , it always gives  `"Unauthorized."`

I have searched so many same question but any of not working for me , so I ask this question again

when user suceessfull login , following token has been stored in localstorage.

[image]

When I tried from Postman rest client

> - it gives unauthorized when i use  `passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}`

[image]

> - it show error  {name:    'JsonWebTokenError', message: 'invalid signature' } passport    middleware when i use isAuthenticate

[image]

I am using this package version :

```
"passport": "^0.4.0",

  "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",

  "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
```

Here is my **helpers/passport.js**

```
const options = {};
options.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
options.secretOrKey = 'qwer123poiuasdf234092482094';
module.exports = passport => {
  passport.use(
    new JwtStrategy(options, (jwt_payload, done) => {

      User.findById(jwt_payload._id)
        .then(user => {
          if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
          }
          return done(null, false);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          return done(err, false);
        });
    })
  );
};
```

Here is my **server.js**

```
global.express = require('express');
global.app = express();

global.passport = require('passport');
global.jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
global.JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
global.ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

global.logger = require('morgan');
global.Validator = require('validator');

global.bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
global.crypto = require('crypto');
global.bodyParser = require('body-parser');
global.cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
global.requireTree = require('require-tree');
global.mongoose = require('mongoose');
global.autoIncrement=require('mongoose-auto-increment');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
var mongooseOptions = {  useNewUrlParser: true }
global.Schema = mongoose.Schema;
autoIncrement.initialize(mongoose);

global.rootdir = __dirname;
global.ejs=require('ejs');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')


global.configuration = requireTree(rootdir + '/configuration')
global.helpers = requireTree(rootdir + '/helpers')
require(rootdir+'/helpers/passport')(passport)
global.validation = requireTree(rootdir + '/validation')

mongoose.connect(configuration.config.MONGODB_URI, mongooseOptions, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('System could not connect to mongo server.')
        console.log(err)
        process.exit()
    } else {
        console.log('System connected to mongo server.')
    }
});


app.use(logger('dev'));  
app.use(passport.initialize())

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
    limit: '50mb',
    parameterLimit: 100000
}))
app.use(bodyParser.json({
    limit: '50mb',
    parameterLimit: 100000
}))


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    next();
});


 // this function i want to use as middleware on private routes

global.isAuthenticated=function(req, res, next) {

     if (req.headers.authorization) {
        passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}, function (err, user, info) {
            console.log('errr==',err);
            console.log('user==',user);
            console.log('info==',info);

            if ((!err || !info) && user) {
                req.user = user;
                return next();
            }
            res.status(401).json({status:'error',isAuthenticated: false, message: "Unauthorized"});
        })(req, res, next);
    } else {

        res.status(401).json({status:'error',isAuthenticated: false, message: "Unauthorized"});
    } 
} 

app.use('/api/auth',routes.api.auth);

var port = process.env.PORT || 8888;
app.listen(port);
```

here is **routes/api/auth.js**

```
const router=express.Router();

router.get('/current',isAuthenticated,(req,res)=>{
    res.json({
        user:req.user
      });
});

module.exports =router
```

please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the 'Could not get any response' error is not due to the authentication error, it might be because server is down or API route is not there.

Second, make sure you are using you have configured token to have Bearer otherwise send only token(without Bearer).

> I think in your case, you are not sending correct token(try removing
>   Bearer) from client.

Comment: I have tried both , removing Bearer , and not removing bearer : i got Unauthorized

Comment: please tell me what should i do now ?